# primer3_core Error: First line must be "Primer3 File - http://primer3.sourceforge.net"

Tags: linux, primer3

I am currently using Primer3 2.3.6 in Linux. I am using the command "primer3_core -p3_settings_file=/my/path/to/settingsfile.txt /my/path/to/inputfile.txt".

I also tried it in Windows 7 and it worked without any problem. However, in Linux I got the error message "primer3_core: First line must be "Primer3 File - http://primer3.sourceforge.net"..". But the missing line is in the first line of my settings file.

Do you have any suggestions or ideas what could be wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I could solve the problem. It was more a mistake of myself, because I edited the default settings file, provided by primer3, using word pad in windows. Thereby, I changed the formatting and primer3 was not able to use it anymore.
Now I just use the text editor or visual studio to change parameters in the settings file.